# Multiple django apps in one wsgi server + nginx

Tags: django, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi, gunicorn

I have deployed multiple django projects in one server using nginx + gunicorn.

Problem is every time when I deploy new django project, I run new instance of gunicorn and configure nginx. Basically if I have 3 projects I have at least 3x3=9 gunicorn related processes. (1 gunicorn related worker, 2 serving django related processes, I have one core so I made 2workers)

Consider the situation you have one big powerfull server and you want to host lots of django apps there like php hosting providers do, but I am thinking running 3processes for every django app just wasting resources.

Is there any way I can run one gunicorn with 10-20 workers, but using them serve 30-50 django apps?